# After I have loaded an image, cropped and drawn it onto a canvas, how can I allow the user to rotate the image before base64 conversion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I crop to square and draw an image to canvas

```
    if(img.height >= img.width) {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 110, 110 * img.height / img.width);
    } else {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0 , 0, 110 * img.width / img.height, 110);
    }
```

After the image is drawn, I convert to base64 using `canvas.toDataURL();` and POST to server.

However before I convert and POST I would like to allow the user the ability to rotate the image 90 degrees before it's converted to base64.

I have a test setup [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Cp98t/2/)

Comment: rotate is before draw...

Comment: pull the image from the canvas, rotate, redraw, save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to rotate your cropped image on a temporary canvas:

Then you can do tempCanvas.toDataURL for your POST.

- create a temporary offscreen canvas
- resize the temp canvas to fit resized+rotated image
- translate to the middle of the temp canvas
- rotate by 90 degrees
- draw the resized image on the temp canvas

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/VrV38/

[image]

Sample code:

```
// create a temporary canvas

var tempCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
var tempCtx=tempCanvas.getContext('2d');

// resize the tempCanvas

tempCanvas.width=h;
tempCanvas.height=w;

// translate+rotate and draw the resized image to tempCanvas

tempCtx.translate(h/2,w/2);
tempCtx.rotate(Math.PI/2);
tempCtx.drawImage(canvas, 0,0,w,h, -w/2,-h/2,w,h);
```